# Ant: fileset: include vs. filename

Tags: ant, include, filenames, fileset

I would like to know what the difference is between the following
in an build.xml file if any, as to me it seems like they do the
same thing:

1.

```
<fileset dir="${source}">
    <include name="**/*.java"/>
</fileset>
```

2.

```
<fileset dir="${source}">
    <filename name="**/*.java"/>
</fileset>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference. Both filesets will include the same files.